# Read blocks from a file object until x bytes from the end

Tags: python, buffer, block, chunks, file-read

I need to read chunks of 64KB in loop, and process them, but **stop at the end of file minus 16 bytes**: the last 16 bytes are a `tag` metadata.

The file might be super large, so I can't read it all in RAM.

All the solutions I find are a bit clumsy and/or unpythonic.

```
with open('myfile', 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        block = f.read(65536)
        if not block:
            break
        process_block(block)
```

If `16 <= len(block) < 65536`, it's easy: it's the last block ever. So `useful_data = block[:-16]` and `tag = block[-16:]`

If `len(block) == 65536`, it *could* mean three things: that the full block is useful data. Or that this 64KB block is in fact **the last block**, so `useful_data = block[:-16]` and `tag = block[-16:]`. Or that this 64KB block is followed by another block of only a few bytes (let's say 3 bytes), so in this case: `useful_data = block[:-13]` and `tag = block[-13:] + last_block[:3]`.

**How to deal with this problem in a nicer way than distinguishing all these cases?**

Note:

- the solution should work for a file opened with `open(...)`, but also for a `io.BytesIO()` object, or for a distant SFTP opened file (with `pysftp`).
- I was thinking about getting the file object size, with

  ```
  f.seek(0,2)
  length = f.tell()
  f.seek(0)
  ```

  Then after each

  ```
  block = f.read(65536)
  ```

  we can know if we are far from the end with `length - f.tell()`, but again the full solution does not look very elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just read in every iteration `min(65536, L-f.tell()-16)`

Something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

L = Path('myfile').stat().st_size

with open('myfile', 'rb') as f:
    while True:    
        to_read_length = min(65536, L-f.tell()-16)
        block = f.read(to_read_length)
        process_block(block)
        if f.tell() == L-16
            break
```

Did not ran this, but hope you get the gist of it.

Comment: Nice solution! I'd replace `st_size` with `f.seek(0, 2); L = f.tell(); f.seek(0)` so that it works for any file object, not only for filesystem files.

Comment: I'm hesitating about writing the `tag` at the beginning of the file (thus requiring a few `f.seek()` because the tag is only computed when the rest of the file is written) or keep it at the end + use this solution. What would you do in [this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64951915/encrypt-a-big-file-that-does-not-fit-in-ram-with-aes-gcm/64959223#64959223) @LiorCohen?

Comment: if you know in advance what room you need for your tag, I would put the tag in the beginning. and when I know it seek back to 0, and write it. Just be careful not to overwrite the first block.

Answer (score 1):

The following method relies only on the fact that the `f.read()` method returns an empty bytes object upon end of stream (EOS). It thus could be adopted for sockets simply by replacing `f.read()` with `s.recv()`.

```py
def read_all_but_last16(f):
    rand = random.Random()  #  just for testing
    buf = b''
    while True:
        bytes_read = f.read(rand.randint(1, 40))  # just for testing
        # bytes_read = f.read(65536)
        buf += bytes_read
        if not bytes_read:
            break
        process_block(buf[:-16])
        buf = buf[-16:]
    verify(buf[-16:])
```

It works by always leaving 16 bytes at the end of `buf` until EOS, then finally processing the last 16. Note that if there aren't at least 17 bytes in `buf` then `buf[:-16]` returns the empty bytes object.